# 2-wire: TWINT is never set in TWCR after start condition is sent

Tags: c, arduino, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I'm using the ATmega328P TWI interface as follows.

**The problem** is that it goes into an infinite loop strobing the LED, and never turns the LED off. If I change the condition to `TRUE` then it turns the LED off and continues.

I've made it explicit which bits are being set; let me know what more detail would be helpful.

```c
PASS_T twi_master_tx(U8_T addr, U8_T* data, SIZE_T len)
{
    /* Set TWINT, TWSTA, and TWEN */
    TWCR.byte = (1u << 7) | (1u << 5) | (1u << 2);

    /* Wait for start condition to be sent. */
    while (FALSE == TWCR.bits.TWINT) {
        dsc_led_toggle(DSC_LED_CANBOARD_1);
    }
    dsc_led_set(DSC_LED_CANBOARD_1, OFF);
    ...
```

It compiles to

```
    1dc6:   84 ea           ldi r24, 0xA4   ; 164
    1dc8:   80 93 bc 00     sts 0x00BC, r24 ; 0x8000bc <__DATA_REGION_ORIGIN__+0x5c>
    1dcc:   80 91 bc 00     lds r24, 0x00BC ; 0x8000bc <__DATA_REGION_ORIGIN__+0x5c>
    1dd0:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
    1dd2:   87 ff           sbrs    r24, 7
    1dd4:   14 c0           rjmp    .+40        ; 0x1dfe <twi_master_tx.constprop.15+0x38>
```

So we know that the register (0x00BC) is being set, the register is being read, and the TWINT bit (7) is being tested.

What am I missing? I thought I'm following the datasheet to the letter (in particular, page 185), but TWINT never gets set to indicate end of START transmission.

According to the datasheet (page 180), SCL frequency = CPU clock / (16 + 2 * TWBR * Prescale). I have TWBR and Prescale set to 0, so I should be getting 16-MHz / 16 = 1-MHz.

**Note:** I'm not using the avr-gcc standard libraries, I'm using my own because this is a learning exercise. I'm aware that bit fields are not recommended, but I think we see that the assembly generated is correct. Here is how my registers are linked:

```
SECTIONS {
  /* TWI */
  TWBR          = 0xB8;
  TWSR          = 0xB9;
  TWAR          = 0xBA;
  TWDR          = 0xBB;
  TWCR          = 0xBC;
  TWAMR         = 0xBD;
  ...
```

Comment: The code you present here does not contain any errors. So the problem must be somewhere else. Do you have the clock set correctly? Or don't you have a hard short on SDA or SCK?

Comment: @PeterPlesník Thanks for looking it over. I've got the clock set by setting TWBR and Prescale to 0, which should yield SCL of 1-MHz. I added an edit about that. No shorts, the pins are open.

Comment: Are the pins fully open? No pull-up resistors? Then connect a 10k pull-up resistor. Otherwise, no start condition can be generated there.
I have no experience with CLK at 1MHz I2C, although it is possible that it works. Why don't you use the standard speed of 100kHz or max 400kHz?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) on Page 199:

Have you set everything? Is the baudrate defined correctly, is the bus free or are there other masters? Check the signals on the bus with an oscilloscope!

Check if the bitrate and the prescaler are set correctly:

```c
TWBR = ???;
TWSR = ???;
```

Normaly the start condition should work:

```c
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWSTA) | (1<<TWEN); // Start a TWI transmission
                            
// Check if START done
while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)))
  asm volatile("NOP");
```

Also it is necessary to pull up SCL and SDA to VCC. This can be done with the internal pull-ups or with external ones. Internal pullups can be enabled through the `PORT` register:

```c
PORTX = (1<<SCL_PIN_POSITION) | (1<<SDA_PIN_POSITION);

// For TQFP/MLF Package:
PORTC = (1<<PINC5) | (1<<PINC4);
```

> Note: With internal pull-ups enabled the bus speed should be screwed down a bit. Otherwise errors in transmission can be the result.